# Remove last element from url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove the last part of the url from a span..

I have

```
<span st_url="http://localhost:8888/careers/php-web-developer-2"
st_title="PHP Web Developer 2" class="st_facebook_large" displaytext="facebook"
st_processed="yes"></span></span>
```

And I need to take the `st_url` and remove the `php-web-developer-2` from it so it is just `http://localhost:8888/careers/`.

But I am not sure how to do that. `php-web-developer-2` will not always be that but it won't have any `/` in it. It will always be a `-` separated string.

Any Help!!??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('span').attr('st_url', function(i, url) {
    var str = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '$';
    return url.replace( new RegExp(str), '' );
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LNW4V/229/)**

Comment: Plz note that this solution is not generic. If the last part of your URL happens to occur elsewhere in the URL too, this will give wrong result; e.g. 'http://somewhere.com/test/e' will fail. Gisway's answer appears to be better.

Comment: This solution has a very big bug because if the url is `"http://localhost:8888/careers1/careers"` the result will be `"http://localhost:8888/1/careers"`, the first `"careers"` is removed

Comment: Your demo needs some work as it does not demonstrate a solution.

Answer (score 20):

**as simple as this:**

```
var to = url.lastIndexOf('/');
to = to == -1 ? url.length : to + 1;
url = url.substring(0, to);
```

Comment: It's work better because if you have some word match with the path, the replace will work removing the first match

Comment: Does not work for Wordpress where the url has a trailing slash.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a slightly simpler way:

```
url = url.slice(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: This is a slick solution; but how could you alter this code to allow for more than one element to be removed, not just the last one?

Comment: I haven't tried it but you should be able to apply this line of code once for each element you want to remove from the end of the url. Or put it in a loop with a counter. HTHs.

Comment: For someone that doesn't know how that would appear (hence my original question), your answer isn't particularly helpful, more frustrating than anything! Are you able to post an example of your suggested code? Based on your comment, do you mean: ```url = url.slice(0, url.lastIndexOf('/').slice(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));```?

Answer (score 12):

Use this.

```
$('span').attr('st_url', function(i, url) {
    var to = url.lastIndexOf('/') +1;

    x =  url.substring(0,to);
    alert(x);
})​
```

You can see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crwM4/1/)

Comment: Remove the `+1` if you wish to eliminate the trailing slash

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regular expression to parse the 'last piece of the url':

```
var url="http://localhost:8888/careers/php-web-developer";

var baseurl=url.replace(new RegExp("(.*/)[^/]+$"),"$1");
```

The RegExp thing basically says: "match anything, then a slash and then all non-slashes till the end of the string".

The replace function takes that matching part, and replaces it with the "anything, then a slash" part of the string.

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) has a great deal of information on all this.

Comment: Upvoted. Best way to match the 'end of the string' in my opinion.  But I, for the record, still hate regex solutions by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/xKxLR/

```
var url = "http://localhost:8888/careers/php-web-developer-2";
var regex = new RegExp('/[^/]*$');
console.log(url.replace(regex, '/'));
```

Comment: hm... I was doubting about the `*` or `+`...  Your version allows an empty tail "http://xxx/yyy/", mine doesn't, both seem to work (in mine, no replace is performed, I guess)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse the  tag. Next try to extract st_url value which is your url. Then use a loop from the last character of the extracted url and omit them until you see a '/'. This is how you should extract what you want. Keep this in mind and try to write the code .