# PHP - remove last part from URL

Tags: php, wordpress

Good day to all!

I need to grab article's URL and modify it by deleting the last part of it (moving one level up).

Grabbing the current URL with Wordpress function `<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>`

Example of use. My current article's URL:

```
http://example.com/apples/dogs/coffee
```

Delete the last part of URL so it will be:

```
http://example.com/apples/dogs
```

(And with no slash at the end)

So this will return the current Wordpress URL:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>">Text</a>
```

but how can I delete the last part of it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), that should get you started.

Comment: The format of the URL depends upon the settings for the WP site. Won't this break if it's not using a rewrite URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430208/php-how-to-remove-last-part-of-a-path

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove last element from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886727/remove-last-element-from-url)

Comment: None of the link you guys mention point the correct solution. This is a wordpress question, so is not a duplicate of the php questions.

Comment: To anyone who is interested, I've chosen `<?php echo dirname(get_permalink( $post->ID )); ?>` as a solution for this task.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://example.com/apples/dogs/coffee';
$newurl = dirname($url);
```

Comment: Thanks! This one seems to be the simpliest and most accurate solution for my case. I modified it a little according to Wordpress, so it is now an ideal solution for me: 

`<?php echo dirname(get_permalink( $post->ID )); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers written here would work, but it's a bad practice to parse a url using `explode` and RegExp. It's better to use the PHP function `parse_url`. In this case, you can't encounter a problem if the url changes. This code will omit the last part of the url's fragment.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://example.com/apples/dogs/coffee';
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
$fragment = isset($parsed_url['path']) ? $parsed_url['path'] : '';
$host = isset($parsed_url['host']) ? $parsed_url['host'] : '';
$scheme = isset($parsed_url['scheme']) ? $parsed_url['scheme'] : '';
$new_fragment = '';
if(!empty($fragment)){
    $fragment_parts = explode('/', $fragment);
    // Remove the last item
    array_pop($fragment_parts);
    // Re-assemble the fragment
    $new_fragment = implode('/', $fragment_parts);
}
// Re-assemble the url
$new_url = $scheme . '://' . $host . $new_fragment;
echo $new_url;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are simply looking for a posts' parent. That being the case you need to use 'get_post_ancestors($post->ID)'.

From the wordpress [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors)...

```
</head>
<?php

/* Get the Page Slug to Use as a Body Class, this will only return a value on pages! */
$class = '';
/* is it a page */
if( is_page() ) { 
    global $post;
        /* Get an array of Ancestors and Parents if they exist */
    $parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
        /* Get the top Level page->ID count base 1, array base 0 so -1 */ 
    $id = ($parents) ? $parents[count($parents)-1]: $post->ID;
    /* Get the parent and set the $class with the page slug (post_name) */
        $parent = get_page( $id );
    $class = $parent->post_name;
}
?>

<body <?php body_class( $class ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you're asking -

```
 echo implode('/',array_slice(explode('/',get_permalink( $post->ID )),0,-1))
```

but it's weak.

Only use as solution as simple as this if you can guarantee you won't have any additional stuff at the end of the URL that you need to keep.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is also working! But `<?php echo dirname(get_permalink( $post->ID )); ?>` looks just a little bit more effective to me.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways (explode, strpos and substr, regex). Using regex you can do something like this:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/apples/dogs/coffee';
$url = preg_replace('#/[^/]+?$#', '', $url);
```