# JS/jQuery Remove Last Part of URL With or Without Trailing Slash

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are answers on how to remove the last part of a URL, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15492273/1005607), but I need to remove the last part of a URL **with OR without a trailing slash**. So I can't just split by `/`.

Examples:

```
http://myapp.com/myapp/advanced-search  -->  http://myapp.com/myapp/
http://myapp.com/myapp/advanced-search/ -->  http://myapp.com/myapp/
```

Any good solutions? I need this for `window.location.href`.

Comment: Doing this on the client side in JS seems a very odd choice. Server side routing is a much better approach.

Comment: Come on Rory, this is needed for `window.location.href` on the client side, surely this isn't hard to understand.

Comment: Now you've added in the line about 'needing it for window.location.href' then the purpose becomes clearer; you're trying to hack a string around. Originally it read as though you were trying to amend the current page URL. In any case a member with 5k+ rep should know how to provide enough useful detail in a question and also show the code they attempted themselves so it can be debugged by others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var url = "http://myapp.com/myapp/advanced-search"; // or http://myapp.com/myapp/advanced-search/
url.replace(/[^\/]+\/?$/,'');
```